# How to modify elements of primitive types in array recursion function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

For example, in c++, I want a function to modify different depths of vector at the same way, I can:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
template <typename V>
void f(V& v){
    for(auto& e : v)
        f(e);
    printf("\n");
}

template <>
void f(int& v){
    v=v*v;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v1={1,2};
    f(v1);
    for(int& i : v1)
        printf("%d ",i);
    printf("\n");

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > v2={{3,4},{5,6,7}};
    f(v2);
    for(std::vector<int> v : v2){
        printf("[");
        for(int& i : v)
            printf("%d ",i);
        printf("]");
    }
    return 0;
};
```

which squares the numbers inside the vector:

```
1 4
[9 16 ][25 36 49 ]
```

In javascript I can return a newly modified array:

```js
var f=function(v){
  if(Array.isArray(v)){
    var v2=[];
    for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++)
      v2.push(f(v[i]));   
    return v2;
  }else
    return v*v;
}
console.log(f([1,2]));
console.log(f([[3,4],[5,6,7]]));
```

But this solution has one thing I want to improve: it creates a new array instead of modifying the original one. Is there any solution that can modify the contents of arrays instead of creating a new one which is similar to the C++ versions?

I know I can't pass primitive types by values in javascript directly, which I may need something like that:

```js
var obj={val:1};
var f=function(ob){
  ob.val=2;
};
f(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

but I don't know how to apply the above technique in my case. Is there any solution like that:

```
var f=function(v){
  if(Array.isArray(v)){
    for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++)
      f(v[i]);   
  }else
    //replace v with v*v
}
```

which can replace the element in the original array?

Comment: What you're trying to do can be done `JavaScript`. Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634932/how-to-modify-elements-of-primitive-types-in-array-recursion-function/48635109#48635109) for a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify arrays in `JavaScript`, so you don't need to create and return a new array, but to simply modify the existing one using functions that can mutate it, like [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) or [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

**Snippet:**

```js
/* The squaring function. */
var square = function(v) {
  if (Array.isArray(v)) {
    for(var i = 0, l = v.length; i < l; i++) {
      /* Remove the current element and add its square in its place. */
      v.splice(i, 1, square(v[i]));
    }
    return v;
  }
  else return v * v;
}

/* Create a sample array and log it. */
var original = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(original);

/* Square the values of the array and log it */
square(original);
console.log(original);
```

**Note:** You still have to return the array inside the `square` function, otherwise the function won't work as expected when it's executed recursively.

Answer (score -1):

If instead of pushing to the v2 array you write directly to the v array, that would accomplish what you are after

```
var f = function(v){
  if(Array.isArray(v)){
    for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++)
      v[i] = f(v[i]);
    return v;
  }else
    return v*v;
}
```